# Mandarin translation of "hidden gem"

Tags: word-choice, idioms

Is there an equivalent to something being called a "hidden gem" in Mandarin, particularly referring to a travel destination, restaurant or an experience?

For example: "This trail is a hidden gem."

Some options I found are: 滄海遺珠 or 不易發覺的美麗, but I'm not sure how suitable they are in my context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

秘寶 (secret treasure) can be used as a noun or adjective

Example:

這餐廳是一個秘寶 --> This restaurant is a hidden gem (only a few know)

工業城中一間秘寶法國餐館 --> A hidden gem of a French restaurant in Industry City (no one expected it exists there)

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for modern netizen speak, an option would be 宝藏

这家店是宝藏呀，东西又便宜又好吃。

Answer (score 0):

A “Hidden Gem” is **something that isn’t well known or popular** but has **something special or unique** about it that inspires positive feelings. I think the phrase "滄海遺珠" fits the definition well, as well as "隐密寶物/藏" and "未發掘的珍寶/未發現的美麗".